# Streaming SSE to Angular Client from AWS using API gateway

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, server-sent-events

What are some ways to support Server-Sent Events in AWS transmitting to an Angular Client? We have a microservice based AWS backend using an API gateway and lambdas. We would like to publish real-time data to Angular Clients (only one way communication). I am interested in knowing about the solutions AWS offers for this.

So far, I came across this, which seem to have duplex communication using Websocket API, but not one-way communication to save costs.

https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/